# how to send a flask base_url to js file through html

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I have to send a `base_url` of an flask function to `js` file since the url would be dynamic.

I was able to create the `base_url` for a particular flask function like

```
url_of_this_function = request.base_url

root_url = url_of_this_function[:url_of_this_function.rfind('/')]

pointing_url = str(url_for('filter_student'))

filter_pointing_url = ''.join([root_url,pointing_url])
```

I pass it to the `html` page through `render_template`

```
return render_template('mypage.html',\
        student_filter_link=filter_pointing_url,student_state_list=state_list)
```

`mypage.html`

```
<select id='student_state_selected' style='display:inline-block' onchange='get_student_filters({{ student_filter_link }})'>
     <option disabled selected>Select</option>
     {% for item in student_state_list %}
     <option value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
     {% endfor %}
</select>
```

when I try to read this in my `js` script it doesn't work.

```
function get_student_filters(filter_link) {
// Do my stuff
}
```

Is this the correct method to pass the url to the `js`?
Is there a better way or am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: Hi, in your HTML file, add a script tag and in that, write the following js code `const student_filter_link  = {{student_filter_link}}`

Answer (score 2):

```
<select id='student_state_selected' style='display:inline-block' onchange='get_student_filters({{ student_filter_link }})'>
     <option disabled selected>Select</option>
     {% for item in student_state_list %}
     <option value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
     {% endfor %}
</select>
```

I just had to change `onchange='get_student_filters({{ student_filter_link }})'` to `onchange='get_student_filters("{{ student_filter_link }}")'`

It worked!

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: I think that is best to use a Html tag in the header, like the [`<base>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) tag. So you can get the url using `document.getElementsByTagName("base")[0].href` in Js. but don't take it as a recommendation, but as an alternative option :)